# Where the heck is this Dwarven Storehouse I keep hearing about in "Eastern Skyrim"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can someone please be more specific as to is location? I followed some instructions elsewhere that seemed to lead to this storehouse, and it just led me to Kagrenzel, the dwarven ruin with the light pedestal trap, and a huge fall into water at the bottom. That one didn't seem to have jack for dwarven materials unless I missed something.

More specific directions would be much appreciated.  I'm trying to mine/gather dwarven materials.

Comment: I used to buy drawven metal ingots until I found this storeroom while walking to Riften.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure that you are refering to Mzulft and the [Dwarven Storeroom](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarven_Storeroom), just south of Mzulft, located along the easterly most edge of Skyrim. It is located along the easterly side of Eastmarch found on [this map](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/index.php?title=Map_%28Skyrim%29&image=Ertyui-jpg).

**Edit:** It should be noted that Mzulft is off limits (requires a key) until you receive a [certain quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mzulft) but the storeroom is open to the public.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't *directly* answer your question, as I haven't yet heard rumors of a Dwarven "storehouse", I *can* tell you where to get a ridiculous number of Dwemer artifacts.

Nchuand'zel, the ruin beneath [Markarth](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Markarth), is the richest I've yet found.  To give you a sense of scale, I walked out of [Avanchnzel](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Avanchnzel) with the materials to smelt ~100 Dwarven metal ingots.  I have so far carried the materials for *more than 700 ingots* out of Nchuand'zel, and I'm not even sure I've gotten it all.

The spoils are split into two main areas — Calcelmo's Dwemer Museum, and Nchuand'zel itself.  Both are accessible via [Understone Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Understone_Keep) in Markarth (you need to go through the Nchuand'zel Excavation Site to get to the city itself).

The ruin is populated primarily by Falmer, so is largely smash-and-grab.  The museum is patrolled by guards who will attack you if you haven't obtained [Calcelmo](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Calcelmo)'s permission and is a much sneakier affair.

Answer (score 1):

If you fast travel to Mzulft the storeroom will be directly to your right when you load.